# Reading a pickled file, unequal length error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pickle, data-science

I want to read a pickle file in python 3.5. I am using the following code.

The following is my output, I want to load it as pandas dataframe.

when I try to convert into pd Dataframe, using df = pd.DataFrame(df), I am getting the below error.

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

link to data- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lSFBPLbUCluWfPjzolUZKmD98yelTSXt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is pickle confidental? What is size of pickle?

Comment: it is 5 megabytes, I can share the link to pickle

Comment: Super, pleas e do it. Because seems data dependent problem.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lSFBPLbUCluWfPjzolUZKmD98yelTSXt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please find, TIA

Comment: Can you create `5MB` file? Because too large for sample data.

Comment: the minimum size is 94 mb. What should i do Jezreal? I was wrong, none of file is 5 mb.

Comment: It is beeter, can you share it?

Comment: okay thank you, I will share in no time.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10cjsoWFJ46w-2lEsxh6hmuRZlLunatf-/view?usp=sharing

Please find Jejrael. Thank you so much

Comment: this one is something like 94mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `dict comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize,
import pickle

fh = open("imdbnames40.pkl", 'rb')
d = pickle.load(fh)
df = pd.concat({k:json_normalize(v, 'scores', ['best']) for k,v in d.items()})
print (df.head())

                         ethnicity score              best
'Aina Rapoza 0               Asian  0.89             Asian
             1      GreaterAfrican  0.05             Asian
             2     GreaterEuropean  0.06             Asian
             3  IndianSubContinent  0.11  GreaterEastAsian
             4    GreaterEastAsian  0.89  GreaterEastAsian
```

Then if need column from first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('names').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, you are the best. I have also read many other answers by you.